# system verilog uniq on selected members of a struct

Tags: system-verilog, uniq

Can selected members of a struct be constrained to be uniq ?

```
typedef struct {
   typeA a;
   typeB b;
   typeC c;
   typeD d;
} config_t;

rand config_t config[10];
```

For example can I constrain {a, c} to be uniq in config[10] instances ?
If not is what is the recommended method to achieve this intent.

Update: **combined pair {a,c} should be uniq across all config[] instances**

example: [0]={a=ENUM_X, b=0}; [1]={a=ENUM_X, b=1}; [2]={a=ENUM_Y, b=1} ...

Comment: Can you edit your question an explain how two members with two different types are considered unique? Also, do you mean unique within each array element of config, or among all elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is by nesting `foreach` loops

```
constraint uniq {
   foreach (config[i]) foreach (config[j])
        i != j -> !(config[i].a == config[j].a && config[i].c == config[j].c); }
```

Comment: But then I cant achieve something like this : [0]={a=ENUM_X, b=0}; [1]={a=ENUM_X, b=1};

Comment: Sorry, my equation was incorrect, didn't test it. I think I fixed it, but you can do the work of testing it and fixing it again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you mean that the combination of a and c must be unique, not each one separately. if this is the case, I'd try to somehow combine them or concatenate them. then create a **unique** array of that new type and make it equal to a,c of config.

```
constraint unique_ac {
   typeAC aux[];
   aux[i].size() == config.size();
   foreach (config[i]) {
     aux[i] == {config[i].a,config[i].c};
   }
   unique {aux};
}
```